# Migrating from forEachGesture to awaitEachGesture

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an app (with a repeating button) which I'm updating to Compose 1.4.0 and I see that *forEachGesture* is deprecated. It tells me to use *awaitEachGesture* instead.

I'm trying to migrate my code but I have an neverending loop because down.pressed is always true.

Here is the old code which is working.

```
fun Modifier.repeatingClickable(
    interactionSource: InteractionSource,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    maxDelayMillis: Long = 500,
    minDelayMillis: Long = 50,
    delayDecayFactor: Float = .20f,
    onClick: () -> Unit
): Modifier = composed {
    val currentClickListener by rememberUpdatedState(onClick)

    pointerInput(interactionSource, enabled) {
        forEachGesture {
            coroutineScope {
                awaitPointerEventScope {
                    val down = awaitFirstDown(requireUnconsumed = false)
                    val heldButtonJob = launch {
                        var currentDelayMillis = maxDelayMillis
                        while (enabled && down.pressed) {
                            currentClickListener()
                            delay(currentDelayMillis)
                            val nextMillis =
                                currentDelayMillis - (currentDelayMillis * delayDecayFactor)
                            currentDelayMillis = nextMillis.toLong().coerceAtLeast(minDelayMillis)
                        }
                    }
                    waitForUpOrCancellation()
                    heldButtonJob.cancel()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my latest attempt.

```
fun Modifier.repeatingClickable(
    interactionSource: InteractionSource,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    maxDelayMillis: Long = 500,
    minDelayMillis: Long = 50,
    delayDecayFactor: Float = .20f,
    onClick: () -> Unit
): Modifier = composed {
    val currentClickListener by rememberUpdatedState(onClick)

    pointerInput(interactionSource, enabled) {
        awaitEachGesture {
            val down = awaitFirstDown(requireUnconsumed = false)

            while (enabled && down.pressed) {
                var currentDelayMillis = maxDelayMillis

                currentClickListener()

                val nextMillis =
                    currentDelayMillis - (currentDelayMillis * delayDecayFactor)
                currentDelayMillis = nextMillis.toLong().coerceAtLeast(minDelayMillis)
            }
            
            waitForUpOrCancellation()
        }
    }
}
```

How should I migrate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To migrate to `awaitEachGesture`, wrap `enabled` in `rememberUpdatedState` and use that variable where `enabled` was used before. Then inside `awaitEachGesture` create a `CoroutineScope` to use to launch `heldButtonJob`.

```
val currentClickListener by rememberUpdatedState(onClick)
val isEnabled by rememberUpdatedState(enabled)

pointerInput(interactionSource, isEnabled) {
    awaitEachGesture {
        val down = awaitFirstDown(requireUnconsumed = false)
        val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())
        val heldButtonJob = scope.launch {
            var currentDelayMillis = maxDelayMillis
            while (isEnabled && down.pressed) {
                currentClickListener()
                delay(currentDelayMillis)
                val nextMillis =
                    currentDelayMillis - (currentDelayMillis * delayDecayFactor)
                currentDelayMillis = nextMillis.toLong().coerceAtLeast(minDelayMillis)
            }
        }
        waitForUpOrCancellation()
        heldButtonJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

EDIT: After some recent reading, I discovered that we can wrap `awaitEachGesture` in `coroutineScope` and then call `launch` within `awaitEachGesture`'s scope without needing to create our own `Coroutine Scope`:

```
    val currentClickListener by rememberUpdatedState(onClick)
    val isEnabled by rememberUpdatedState(enabled)

    pointerInput(interactionSource, isEnabled) {
        coroutineScope {
            awaitEachGesture {
                val down = awaitFirstDown(requireUnconsumed = false)
                val job = launch {
                    var currentDelayMillis = maxDelayMillis
                    while (isEnabled && down.pressed) {
                        currentClickListener()
                        delay(currentDelayMillis)
                        val nextMillis =
                            currentDelayMillis - (currentDelayMillis * delayDecayFactor)
                        currentDelayMillis = nextMillis.toLong().coerceAtLeast(minDelayMillis)
                    }
                }
                waitForUpOrCancellation()
                job.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. but I have a doubt... parameter in CoroutineScope is needed? I'm still rookie, excuse me :S

Comment: @Clandes, unfortunately, I'm not an expert with Coroutines. This pattern is one I've learned and just use when I need to create a CoroutineScope. Maybe someone with more experience than both of us can answer your question better. :)