# Compose: custom onClick gestures, D-pads, and accessibility

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `Button` with a `Modifier` to act like a keyboard key: it calls a click handler immediately on press, and if held down past a delay it will start repeatedly calling it until release (approximately [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76190587/6540)).

The problem is that every implementation of this that I've seen sets `onClick = {}` on the `Button` itself to avoid a duplicate event (e.g. on release of a short press), which works for pointer input, but means that D-pads, keyboards, and accessibility handlers then can't use the button at all.

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
Button(...,

    //
    // What should this condition be?
    //
    onClick = { if (isNotFromAPointerEvent) doStuff() },

    modifier = repeatingClickable(..., 
        onPressOrRepeat = { doStuff() }
    )
)

fun Modifier.repeatingClickable(
    ...,
    onPressOrRepeat: () -> Unit
): Modifier = composed {
    ...

    //
    // Or can I do something in here to detect non-pointer "click" events?
    //

    pointerInput(interactionSource, enabled) {
        awaitEachGesture {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
    val inputModeManager = LocalInputModeManager.current
    Button(
        onClick = {
            if (inputModeManager.inputMode != Touch) doStuff()
        },
        ...
    )
```

I'm not sure it's 100% correct, since theoretically there could be accessibility software out there that will try to invoke the "semantics" onClick on the button (i.e. the Button's own onClick) while still in Touch mode, right?

But, the only way I can see to avoid that would be "clone and own" the relevant methods of Button, Surface, and Clickable because it's not until ClickableNode that I can see a proper separation between pointer input (where I would put the above custom handling) and semantic onClick (which would then be always-on, to handle both keyboard events and accessibility events in the normal way).

Better answers welcome!